# How can I get the number of existing HTML elements from code before rendering them

Tags: c#, razor

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can filter some HTML elements inside my code.

Basically I have some `div` containers which each contain some stuff I want to display. 
But I only want to display a set amount (e.g. 1 or 3) of those containers which will be chosen at random.
I basically have the logic for choosing them at random already in the code.
The problem I have is that I need to somehow get the amount of containers I actually have to choose from them.
I don't want to depend on the ability of other people who work on the same code to actually update the number of containers manually when they add or delete one.

The containers are in a file looking something like this:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="element1">
        //first container
    </dev>
    <div id="element2">
        //second container
    </dev>
    <div id="element3">
        //third container
    </dev>
</div>
```

I want to get the number of those element from the code so I can filter them before the rendering of the website.
I could do the filtering by using TypeScript or JavaScript but for that I would need to load all the containers first which I want to prevent because of performance/user experience.

Is there any possibility to get like a list of all the containers or something like that?

I would really appreciate some help here :)

Comment: In JavaScript you only have the Option do the Count after everything has been rendered [JavaScript Child element Count](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp) or if These Elements get generated by Code, you could easily use the Count of that model

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cant 'read' the DOM from within a Razor view so what you need is a different way of approaching the problem. How about something like this, which follows your current Razor layout quite closely;

```
@{
    List<string> elementsToRender = new List<string>(5) { "element1", "element3" };
}

<div id="mainContainer">
    @if (elementsToRender.Contains("element1", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        <div id="element1">
            @* first container *@
        </div>
    }
    @if (elementsToRender.Contains("element2", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        <div id="element2">
            @* second container *@
        </div>
    }
    @if (elementsToRender.Contains("element3", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        <div id="element3">
            @* third container *@
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

You can still let other developers add and maintain the elements, all they need to do is make sure each one has a unique key in the `elementsToRender.Contains` test. For simplicity I've used the element wrapper div Id but it doesn't have to be. Then you can control which elements are shown by choosing which keys you add to elementsToRender .

You could move the population of elementsToRender into a ViewModel then populate it dynamically based on whatever logic you want.

Comment: That still depends on the one adding a container to also add that to the `List` element. I would really like to have that automated because I expect people (me included) to forget about that step :/

Answer (score 0):

Taking a different approach to the problem, how about putting the markup for each element into a separate partial view in a known folder. You could then scan the files in the known folder and pick which ones/how many to render into the actual page using [@Html.RenderPartial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).